# Standard ML Foldl/Foldr function with multiplication operator?

Tags: whitespace, fold, smlnj, overload-resolution

For Standard ML (SMLNJ), for the foldr and foldl functions, what is the correct way to use the multiplication operator?

Using `foldr (op *) 1 [1,2,3];` gives an error

> Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
>
> - stdIn:1.12 Error: unmatched close comment
> - stdIn:1.9-1.18 Error: syntax error: deleting  OP INT LBRACKET

It appears that the * has other overloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace normally doesn't matter for SMLNJ. But for the multiplication (asterisk) operation ***it does***.

Make sure you have a space between the asterisk and the closing parenthesis `* )` or it will be interpreted as an unopened comment `*)`.

`foldr (op * ) 1 [1,2,3];`